# How could I get the raw uri based on ngnix+gunicorn?

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, python-3.3, gunicorn

My environment is OS X 10.9.2，python3.3.

I want to use nginx as a reverse server and it redirects the raw url to the gunicorn server to handle with. But I couldn't get the raw url in the handler. Please give me some advice.

The following works fine in Linux, python2.7, but doesn't work in the new environment.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {  
    listen 9000;  
    servername localhost;  

location / {  
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
  }    
  }
```

My handler is :

```
def myhandler(env, start_response):
    url_scheme = env['wsgi.url_scheme']
    host = env['HTTP_HOST']
    path = env['RAW_URI']
    url = '%s://%s%s' % (url_scheme, host, path)

    start_response("200 OK", [
      ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
    ])

return url
```

And I lanuch gunicorn like this:

```
$ gunicorn -w 4 -k tornado app:myhandler
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the worker type of gunicorn.
In the environment of python2.7 and gevent, it will be ok if I do the launch:

```
$ gunicorn -w 4 -k gevent app:myhandler
```